# Impresión térmica en varios terminales

Tags: php, javascript, nodejs, impresora

Me gustaría saber si hay algún método, en algún lenguaje, para poder enviar información de una compra, a un vendedor, de ID "X", para que en la impresora térmica que tenga el vendedor "X" se muestre la factura de lo que le han comprado a él por la web. No sé si me explico.

Hay varios vendedores con varias impresoras térmicas. Yo necesito un lenguaje, me encantaría que fuese PHP pero lo dudo, para poder enviar la información a una determinada impresora térmica. Esos datos, supongo que cada impresora traerá un identificador que deberé añadir al código para poder elegir bien a quién mandar la información.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: El tema que propones es amplio y complejo, pero no está relacionado con el lenguaje sino con otros condicionantes, por ejemplo si es una app web el navegador no te va a permitir el acceso a la impresora del cliente.

Comment: Imprimir programaticamente implica lidiar con los drivers del sistema operativo para esa impresora específica, y/o con lo que esté en el medio, red y/o servidor de impresión. Yo creo que sí o sí como mínimo hay que poner algo de código (ejemplo bash) en el equipo que tiene acceso a la impresora. Puede ser que ya existan programas para hacer de puente, pero seguro lo tienen que correr los equipos que tienen acceso a la impresora. Es decir, si PHP pudiera resolverlo (no lo creo) debería ser ejecutado desde la maquina que tiene conexión con la impresora.

Comment: Ya me imaginaba que tenía que tener control desde el ordenador de la propia impresora para mandar datos allí. No me imagino cómo lo pueden hacer compañías como Uber eats y Just eat para imprimir los tickets de los pedidos del restaurante a elegir, pero seguiré investigando. Muchas gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: Es necesario tener una aplicación que pueda mandar impresiones en la máquina que controla la impresora y conectarte a dicha aplicación de manera remota.

Comment: Cuando se monta una infraestructura de envío desatendido de tickets hay que diferenciar entre un uso local, como en un restaurante donde una comanda desencadena un ticket en la cocina todo en la misma LAN, y un uso global donde un trabajador de una oficina desencadena una orden de trabajo impresa en otra oficina diferente (diferentes LAN). En ambos casos TODAS las impresoras se configuran en el servidor web para que estén disponibles a PHP, ASP, JSP o la tecnología web subyacente, pero en el caso de LAN diferentes hace falta usar VPNs o DNS dinámicas para alcanzar las impresoras de destino.